# Setting database name in EF config section for localdb

Tags: entity-framework, localdb

Entity Framework supports two locations to specify database configuration in app.config. If I add EF5 nuget package to a console app, the app.config contains following markup:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

It uses the default localdb instance which is just fine but it takes the fully qualified type name of `DbContext` as database name. I know I can override this convention by calling ctor of [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
But how can I specify it in configuration file?

Comment: Create a connection string

Comment: Adding a connectonstring in Connectionstrings section would work, but out of curiosity, why is there no way to accomplish this with the default connection factory. If you specify a cs, defaultconnectionfactory is ignored.